# How to combine primaryKey modification with belongsTo in Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've got an odd problem where I need to combine two concepts.  When used individually, the techniques works, when combined, they fail. Basically, when I try to enter a primaryKey into a custom serializer, the belongsTo relationship depending on the primary key fails.

Consider this
[JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cidaye/edit?html,js,output)
that demonstrates the problem.

My API doesn't return an ID in the payload so I use a custom serializer to point to the correct primaryKey.

```
App.ContactSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: 'user_id'
});
```

But this breaks my existing relationship defined in the model.

```
App.Contact = DS.Model.extend({
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  user: DS.belongsTo('user', {async: true})
});
```

How can I have my cake and eat it too?

[JSBin Demo](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cidaye/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much googling, I came up with what appears to be a workable solution:

[Revised JSBin Example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cidaye/edit?html,js,output)
Basically, I can use the Normalize function in the Serializer to add the exptected ID value from the non-standard value my API supplies.

```
// Match serializer to adapter...(ActiveModel)
// use normalize to slip in an id from API
App.ContactSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend({
    normalize: function(typeClass, hash, prop) {
        hash.id = hash.user_id;
        return this._super(typeClass, hash, prop);
    }
});
```